# How to abstract things away in c without having a bunch of function parameters?

Tags: c, design-patterns, parameters, abstraction, procedural-programming

I've been messing around with SDL2 in c and was wondering how to abstract code away without using too many function parameters. For example, in a normal gameplay loop there is usually an input, update, render cycle. Ideally, I would like this to be abstracted as possible so I could have functions called "input", "update", "render", in my loop. How could i do this in c without having those functions take a ludicrous amount of parameters? I know that c++ kind of solves this issue through classes, but I am curious and want to know how to do this in a procedural programming setting.

So far, I can't really think of any way to fix this. I tried looking it up online but only get results for c++ classes. As mentioned before, I want to stick to c because that is what i am comfortable with right now and would prefer to use.

Comment: Use structures to abstract data.

Comment: Questions about software design principles are more appropriate for [softwareengineering.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have complex state to transport some between calls, put that in a struct. Pass a pointer to that as the sole argument to your functions, out at least as the first of very few.

That is a very common design pattern on C code.

```c
void inputstep(struct state_t* systemstate);
void updatestep(struct state_t* systemstate);
void renderstep(struct state_t* systemstate, struct opengl_context_t* oglctx);
```

Note also that it is exactly the same, if not even more (due to less safety about pointers), overhead as having a C++ class with methods.

> this in a functional programming setting.

Well, C is about as far as you get from a purely functional language, so functional programming paradigms only awkwardly translate. Are you sure you didn't mean "procedural"?

In a functional programming mindset, the state you pass into a function would be immutable or discarded after the function, and the function would return a new state; something like

```c
struct mystate_t* mystate;
...
while(1) {
  mystate = inputfunc(mystate);
  mystate = updatefunc(mystate);
  …
}
```

Only that in a functional setting, you wouldn't re-assign to a variable, and wouldn't have a while loop like that. Essentially, you wouldn't write C.

Comment: Thanks so much! This helps a ton. One more question. How would I set up the state_t struct? Obviously I would have the window and renderer pointers in there, but should I also create an array of game objects in there too so those also get passed into the render function? (Also you are right, I did mean procedural programming, sorry. I am still learning all of the different names for the different approaches languages take)

Comment: @Dr-Galunga it should contain references to all the state these functions deal with. The game state. How you do that: well that really depends and you'll find that at some degree of engine complexity things get blurry and you have some external global state that you cannot encapsulate... Really, what you're asking is "how to design a game engine" and that's a tiny bit too broad to be answered.